# Modifying checkboxes from a datalist ( C# / asp.net )

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to modify this asp.net / C# code.  The page lets an admin add a user and choose what roles this user will have from a list of checkboxes.  There are 11 checkboxes with roles next to them to pick from.  I'm wanting to organize these checkboxes.  I'm wanting to divide the 11 checkboxes into 3 groups CMS, LMS, and Admin in order to group them into three sections on the page.  I'm wanting only one checkbox to be selectable for the CMS group.  The CMS group can be a dropdown box if that would make it easier.  And, all of these roles must have a tooltip when the user hovers their mouse over them.

You'll see in the code that the checkboxes get created using the userRolesDataSource.  This datasource uses a method called "GetUserRoles" which has two parameters the "username" and the "onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole" boolean.  The selection method checks if the username is a system admin and excludes all other role choices if this is true.

This is the new GetUserRoles method:

```
public List<Pair<string, bool>> GetUserRoles(
            string userName, bool onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole)
    {
        // Return a list of "role name"/"has role" pairs for the given user.
        // If the "onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole" flag is true, only return the
        // "System Admin" role, otherwise return all roles other than
        // "System Admin".
        List<Pair<string, bool>> userRolesList = null;

        if (!onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole)
        {
            string[] allRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

            HashSet<string> rolesForUser = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
            {
                rolesForUser = new HashSet<string>(
                        Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName));
            }

            userRolesList = (from roleName in allRoles
                             where roleName != RoleNames.SYSTEM_ADMIN
                             select new Pair<string, bool>()
                             {
                                 First = roleName,
                                 Second = rolesForUser != null
                                     ? rolesForUser.Contains(roleName)
                                     : false
                             }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            userRolesList = new List<Pair<string, bool>>()
            {
                new Pair<string, bool>(
                        RoleNames.SYSTEM_ADMIN,
                        Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, RoleNames.SYSTEM_ADMIN))
            };
        }

        return userRolesList;
    }
```

Something like that will still have to be run on all the checkboxes.

In order to solve the problem I planned on using something like this method.  It can be given a list of roles as a parameter.  And, it'll exclude the list provided and return every other role.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRoles(params string[] roleNamesToExclude)
    {
        var query = Uow.Roles
            .AsQueryable()
            .Select(r => r.RoleName);

        if (roleNamesToExclude != null && roleNamesToExclude.Any())
        {
            query = query
                .Where(r => !roleNamesToExclude.Contains(r));
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

My idea for re-building it was to replace userRolesDataSource with 3 new datasources: CMSRolesDataSource, LMSRolesDataSource, AdminRolesDataSource.  Then create a new method that takes username, systemadmin boolean, as well as a list of excludable roles like the method above.

I'm still pretty new to coding and I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of doing all of this.  The code to the asp and c# are below.  Thanks in advance.

asp

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="userRolesDataSource" runat="server" OnSelecting="userRolesDataSource_Selecting" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetUserRoles" TypeName="VirtualExpertClinics.AutismProClassroom.Data.UserBLL">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="userName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole" Type="Boolean" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="titlesDataSource" runat="server"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetOrganizationTitles"
        TypeName="VirtualExpertClinics.AutismProClassroom.Data.OrganizationBLL"
        OnSelecting="titlesDataSource_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="organizationId" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

            <h5><%: Resources.Global.UserRoles %></h5>
            <asp:DataList ID="userRolesDataList" runat="server" CssClass="formTable" DataSourceID="userRolesDataSource" Enabled="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="userRoleCheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("Second") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="userDetailsPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="saveButton">
                <table class="formTable extraCellPadding">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignTop">
                            <asp:Label ID="userRolesLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, UserRoles %>"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="userRolesCustomValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validationGroup"
                                OnServerValidate="userRolesCustomValidator_ServerValidate" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                            <asp:DataList ID="userRolesDataList" runat="server" CssClass="formTable" OnItemDataBound="userRolesDataList_ItemDataBound" DataSourceID="userRolesDataSource">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="userRoleCheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("Second") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div style="margin-top: 1em;">
                    <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" ValidationGroup="validationGroup" CommandName="Update" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Save %>" />
                    <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" CommandName="Cancel" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Cancel %>" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </EditItemTemplate>


        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="userDetailsPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="saveButton">
                <table class="formTable extraCellPadding">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignTop">
                            <asp:Label ID="userRolesLabel" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, UserRoles %>"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="userRolesCustomValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validationGroup"
                                OnServerValidate="userRolesCustomValidator_ServerValidate" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                            <asp:DataList ID="userRolesDataList" runat="server" CssClass="formTable" OnItemDataBound="userRolesDataList_ItemDataBound" DataSourceID="userRolesDataSource">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="userRoleCheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("Second") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="margin-top: 1em;">
                    <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" ValidationGroup="validationGroup" CommandName="Insert" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Save %>" />
                    <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" CommandName="Cancel" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Cancel %>" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</div>
```

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (SessionWrapper.ActiveUserID == null)
            {
                userFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void detailDataSource_Inserting(
            object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList userRolesDataList = (DataList)userFormView.Row.FindControl(
                "userRolesDataList");

        List<string> roles = GetSelectedUserRoles(userRolesDataList);

        if (SessionWrapper.WorkingOrganizationId != null)
        {
            e.InputParameters["organizationId"]
                = SessionWrapper.WorkingOrganizationId;
        }
        else
        {
            e.InputParameters["organizationId"]
                = SessionWrapper.ActiveOrganizationID;
        }

        e.InputParameters["acceptedAgreement"] = false;
        e.InputParameters["changedPassword"] = false;
        e.InputParameters["mustUpdateProfile"] = true;
        e.InputParameters["timeZoneId"] = TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id;
        e.InputParameters["roles"] = roles;
        e.InputParameters["registrationCodeId"] = null;
        e.InputParameters["createPasswordTicket"] = true;

        MiscUtil.TrimInputParameters(e.InputParameters);
    }



    protected void detailDataSource_Updating(
            object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList userRolesDataList = (DataList)userFormView.Row.FindControl(
                "userRolesDataList");

        e.InputParameters["roles"] = GetSelectedUserRoles(userRolesDataList);

        UserProfileDS.UserProfileRow user = UserBLL.GetUserByUserID(
                (Guid)userFormView.SelectedValue);

        e.InputParameters["acceptedAgreement"] = user.AcceptedAgreement;
        e.InputParameters["changedPassword"] = user.ChangedPassword;
        e.InputParameters["mustUpdateProfile"] = user.MustUpdateProfile;
        e.InputParameters["timeZoneId"] = user.TimeZoneId;

        MiscUtil.TrimInputParameters(e.InputParameters);
    }


    protected void userRolesDataList_ItemDataBound(
            object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Pair<string, bool> rolePair = (Pair<string, bool>)e.Item.DataItem;

        if (rolePair.First == RoleNames.CMS_OWNER
                || rolePair.First == RoleNames.CMS_DATA_ENTRY
                || rolePair.First == RoleNames.CMS_BROWSER)
        {
            // Disable the CMS roles if CMS access is not enabled for the
            // current organization.
            OrganizationDS.OrganizationRow organizationRow
                    = OrganizationBLL.GetOrganizationById(
                            SessionWrapper.ActiveOrganizationID);

            if (!organizationRow.EnableCMS)
            {
                CheckBox userRoleCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl(
                        "userRoleCheckBox");

                userRoleCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                userRoleCheckBox.ToolTip = Resources.Global.CMSNotEnabled;
            }
        }
        else if (rolePair.First == RoleNames.WORKSHOPS_USER)
        {
            // Disable the "Workshops User" role if the corresponding
            // check box is not selected and the current organization has
            // reached their maximum number of learners.
            if (!rolePair.Second
                    && OrganizationBLL.HasReachedMaxLearners(
                            SessionWrapper.ActiveOrganizationID))
            {
                CheckBox userRoleCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl(
                        "userRoleCheckBox");

                userRoleCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                userRoleCheckBox.ToolTip
                        = Resources.Global.OrganizationMaxLearnersReached;
            }
        }
        else if (rolePair.First == RoleNames.LOCAL_SYSTEM_ADMIN)
        {
            // Disable the "Local System Admin" role if the current user
            // is not a system admin.
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(RoleNames.SYSTEM_ADMIN))
            {
                CheckBox userRoleCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl(
                        "userRoleCheckBox");

                userRoleCheckBox.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void userRolesDataSource_Selecting(
            object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName;
        bool onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole;

        if (userFormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
            userName = "";
            onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole
                    = (SessionWrapper.ActiveOrganizationID == 0);
        }
        else
        {
            UserProfileDS.UserProfileRow userRow
                    = (UserProfileDS.UserProfileRow)userFormView.DataItem;

            userName = userRow.UserName;
            onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole = Roles.IsUserInRole(
                    userRow.UserName, RoleNames.SYSTEM_ADMIN);
        }

        e.InputParameters["userName"] = userName;
        e.InputParameters["onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole"]
                = onlyIncludeSystemAdminRole;
    }


    private List<string> GetSelectedUserRoles(DataList userRolesDataList)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataListItem item in userRolesDataList.Items)
        {
            CheckBox userRoleCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl(
                    "userRoleCheckBox");

            if (userRoleCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                roles.Add(userRoleCheckBox.Text);
            }
        }

        return roles;
    }

    protected void userRolesCustomValidator_ServerValidate(
          object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        CustomValidator userRolesCustomValidator = (CustomValidator)source;
        DataList userRolesDataList = (DataList)userFormView.Row.FindControl(
                "userRolesDataList");

        List<string> roles = GetSelectedUserRoles(userRolesDataList);

        AdministrationUtil.ValidateUserRoleSelection(
                roles, userRolesCustomValidator, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your use-case for this?  I.E. is this for work, school, personal, etc.  If it isn't for work then there are far easier ways to handle this kind of task using entity framework, jquery and templates to handle a lot of the work on the front end.  Also, do you have a "RoleType" table that groups the roles and a FK on the role table?  If not that will make pulling back the roles and adding them to the right list much easier.

Comment: Thanks Aithos,

This is for work.  There's a role table that its grabbing from but it doesn't have any column for type.  

The ApplicationId column on this table has a FK.  The RoleID, Rolename, LoweredRoleName, and Description column do not.

Comment: Ok, since it's for work that makes it a little tricky because depending on your environment and how your team develops things it may limit how you implement solutions.  If the three groups correspond to specific application IDs you can use those to filter, otherwise you're likely going to have to add at the very least a column to the role table to indicate what group it's for because you don't want to have to hard code it (inflexible, harder to maintain, etc).  The better practice would be to add a RoleType table and then add a RoleTypeId on the Role table with a FK to the RoleType.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance.   I'll keep that in mind for the future.  I was on a time crunch so I ended up hard coding it.  Works well but took quite a while to get finished.